# Does the Native VBA Compiler Optimize?

Tags: vba, optimization, compiler-construction, profiling, compiler-optimization

My code is as follows:

```
#Const debuggingEnabled = False

Sub debugMessage(str As String)
    #If debuggingEnabled Then
        Debug.Print str
    #End If
End Sub

Sub doThings()
    debugMessage "test"   'Does this get optimised away, or must it be explicitly
                          'wrapped with `#If .. #End If` every time it's called
                          'if one is to avoid the jump and stack push/pop ops?
End Sub
```

Does Microsoft's VBA compiler optimise away calls to procedures that do nothing?  How can I find out?

Comment: What is the point in "optimizing away" a single, one-bit, binary, boolean test? Are you sure that this represents a significant portion of execution time? Could be, but the chances are pretty remote. Before optimizing, do some profiling, so you don't spend time and worry on bits of code that represent 0.0001% of your execution time.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Well, I want to have some debugging output during a loop which is repeated many thousands of times - but when debugging is disabled would rather avoid the additional overhead of the ensuing jumps/stack operations.  How can I profile VBA to determine the amount of additional overhead such calls entail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading this from comment to answer:

What is the point in "optimizing away" a procedure containing a single, one-bit, binary, boolean test? Are you sure that this represents a significant portion of execution time? The chances of that are pretty remote.

Before optimizing, always do some profiling, so you don't waste time and worry on bits of code that represent 0.0001% of your execution time.

VBA has no native profiler, but there are third-party options out there, some of them free. This is one, accompanied by an instructive read: [Profiling and Optimizing VBA
By bruce mcpherson](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/excel/12dfc2ae-d796-40e8-9762-572bdaa7b637/profiling-and-optimizing-vba.aspx). A [DuckDuckGo search](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=VBA%20profiling) gives plenty of other leads as well.

So, the answer to your original question is: I don't think VBA optimizes such a procedure away, but I'm not entirely sure, and either way it is in all likelihood completely irrelevant. Before worrying about optimizing, always do some profiling, so you can spend your time wisely. After profiling, you will almost always find that what you thought slowed down your program is actually very fast, and that something else is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the VBA interpreter does little or no optimisation. If you test this in VBE debug mode you can see execution jump to the "empty" sub.
But I would have thought that the additional overhead will anyway be drowned by the rest of the VBA execution.

Comment: Testing what kind of optimizations happen in a debug build while debugging is about as significant as throwing a dice.. (c compilers obviously will optimize such things, but you can still see them entering such a method when debugging..) you'd have to expect the generated native code to be sure and no idea how you do that with VBA (I doubt that it matters much though)

Comment: VBA does not have a debug build and there is no generated native code to inspect. Judging by timing tests on obvious things like removing from loops expressions that don't vary  the VBA Interpreter (its not a compiler in the traditional sense of the word) does little or no optimisation.